# Unrecognized Selector Sent to instance from App Delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am implementing my application with story boards. My app can be opened by custom url 
Here is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:        (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
ADMSBarcodeScanner *controller = (ADMSBarcodeScanner*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"barcode_scanner"];

controller.delegate =self;
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

return true;
}
```

When this written it opens the view controller
ADMSBarcodeScanner.h

```
@protocol senddataProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)sendDataToHomePage:(NSString *)vin;
@end

@interface ADMSBarcodeScanner : UIViewController < ZBarReaderDelegate >  
{

UIImageView *resultImage;
UITextView *resultText;
UIView *cameraView;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *resultText;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *resultField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *cameraView;

@end
```

the corresponding .m file code is

```
[delegate sendDataToHomePage:symbol.data];
[reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

the function is present in ADMSViewController.m

```
 -(void)sendDataToHomePage:(NSString *)vin
{
  UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"VIN" message:vin delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Oke" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

 }
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Here is the error i am getting

```
2014-01-08 15:49:21.466 Autofunds[2476:907] -[ADMSAppDelegate sendDataToHomePage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd30580
2014-01-08 15:49:21.478 Autofunds[2476:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ADMSAppDelegate sendDataToHomePage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd30580'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32c762a3 0x3a8f697f 0x32c79e07 0x32c78531 0x32bcff68 0xd1eb5 0xe51cb 0xeaaef 0xe2ff5 0x3358d0f5 0x32c4b683 0x32c4aee9 0x32c49cb7 0x32bbcebd 0x32bbcd49 0x3676f2eb 0x34ad2301 0xd14d5 0x3ad2db20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please update your question with error message

Comment: The problem is with this line of code "[delegate sendDataToHomePage:symbol.data]", it is of type id, a generic class, it should be cast to the class it has been assigned to make it work.

Comment: Why is the delegate not `id < sendDataProtocol >` ?

Comment: updated the error message.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please accept my answer below and close this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Since your delegate is defined as `id`, this line of code is probably causing the issue:

```
[delegate sendDataToHomePage:symbol.data];
```

You need to update `delegate` declaration with your protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <senddataProtocol> delegate;
```

You also need to claim in the header file of your App Delegate that it implements required methods of the protocol. Your AppDelegate.h should look something like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, senddataProtocol>
```

And finally, implement the method in your AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)sendDataToHomePage:(NSString *)vin {
    blah blah...
}
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: the method is not implemented inside the app delegate. it is in ADMSViewController.m. please check the original question

Comment: cast your delegate to your ADMSViewController and it will work before sending sendDataToHomePage.

Comment: @user2541457: It seems you didn't get how delegate works... The sendDataHomePage should be in the class set as delegate (AppDelegate in this case)

Comment: Why are you implementing protocol if you are calling function from same class? I totally agree with what Larme just said above.

Answer (score 0):

declare your delegate using the protocol you have created

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id <senddataProtocol> delegate
```

Comment: That's not a cast, it's a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You are making appDelegate as the delegate of ADMSBarcodeScanner and implementing delegate method in ADMSViewController.m. May be it is crashing because it is not getting the method implementation there.
Just check for respondToSelector method before calling any protocol method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `delegate` property refers to an `AppDelegate` instance. And you are calling `[delegate sendDataToHomePage]`. And that method is not defined in `AppDelegate`, it's in `ADMSViewController`. So it's obvious that it will crash with that message.

Comment: can u provide a solution for this

Comment: Implement the sendDataToHomePage method in your AppDelegate.m. And to do everything 'a la carte' follow Rinat Khanov's answer. I would also suggest renaming your protocol to start with a capital letter. It's the standard...it's not mandatory but it's nice to follow the rules so that others will read your code easier.

Answer (score 0):

In the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

in your `ADMSAppDelegate` you are setting `controller.delegate = self` so when `sendDataToHomePage` method is called it is looking in the `ADMSAppDelegate` and not in `ADMSViewController` as you think. `self` here in your code is `ADMSAppDelegate`.

And as you have stated

> the function is present in ADMSViewController.m

This method (Function as you have referred to it as) needs to be implemented in `ADMSAppDelegate` otherwise it will always return this error.